# Transmit event to parent component using btable

Tags: laravel, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I'm using laravel (maybe it's not important for this question), with vue and bootstrap-vue.

I have a model `Subnet` and I have created a vue component called `SubnetTable` thats shows a table with a row for each of the `subnets`.
In each a delete button is shown, that launches a modal to confirm the deletion of a subnet (another custom component called `ModalDeleteSubnet`).

Im trying to emit the result of the modal confirmation to the `SubnetTable` component but it does not work. I've realized that `SubnetTable` is not the parent of `ModalDeleteSubnet`:

Root -> SubnetTable -> BTable -> BTBody -> BTableCell -> ModalDeleteSubnet

So, I suppose it's impossible to make the emit work this way...

What is the correct way to create something (I think very common) like this using vue: a table with its action buttons that updates the table data?

Hope I have explained. Sorry about my English.

SubnetTable

```
<template>
    <div>
        <b-card class="text-center">            
            <b-table small striped hover :items="data_subnets" :fields="fields" :tbody-tr-class="rowClass">
                <template slot="[ip_address]" slot-scope="data_subnets">
                    <b>{{ long2ip(data_subnets.item.ip_address) }}</b>
                </template>
              <template slot="[actions]" slot-scope="data_subnets">
                <b-button size="sm" :href="'subnets/'+ data_subnets.item.id">View</b-button>                  
                <modal_edit-subnet></modal_edit-subnet>
                <modal_delete-subnet :subnet="data_subnets.item"></modal_delete-subnet>
              </template>
            </b-table>
        </b-card>
    </div>
</template>
...
...
...
```

modal_delete-subnet

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-button size="sm" @click="showConfirmModal">Delete</b-button>  
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {   
    name: 'Modal_DeleteSubnet',
    props: ['subnet'],
    data(){
      return {              
        data_subnet: this.subnet
      }
    },
    methods : {
      showConfirmModal() {   
        this.$bvModal.msgBoxConfirm('Please confirm that you want to delete the subnet...'
        , {
          title: long2ip(this.data_subnet.ip_address) + '/' + this.data_subnet.netmask,
          size: 'sm',
          buttonSize: 'sm',
          okVariant: 'danger',
          okTitle: 'Yes',
          cancelTitle: 'No',
          footerClass: 'p-2',
          hideHeaderClose: false,
          centered: true
        })
          .then(value => {
            if (value==true)
            {
              this.$emit('deleteSubnet', this.data_subnet.id)
            }
          })
          .catch(err => {
            // An error occurred
          })
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: It would be great if you can provide some code :)

Comment: yeah, sorry. Added some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just transmit it to the parent.

```html
<modal_delete-subnet :subnet="data_subnets.item" @delete-subnet="$emit('delete-subnet', $event)"></modal_delete-subnet>
```

Or if you have your delete handler in `SubnetTable`, handle it here.

```html
<modal_delete-subnet :subnet="data_subnets.item" @delete-subnet="deleteHandler"></modal_delete-subnet>
```

```js
export default {
  ...
  methods: {
    deleteHandler(e) {
      console.log(e)
      // delete actions here
    },
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: It didnt work but it helped me a lot!
I added  v-on:deleteSubnet="deleteSubnet"
instead of @delete-sub...

and it worked.
I also have already createad the related method that performs the delete actions.

Thanks!